# What's the name of the force that opposes the movement of magnet trough a coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, induction, magnetic-flux

I am trying to make an experiment that looks like this:

[image]

[image]

I am using this source https://physicshandson.wordpress.com/2019/02/04/damped-oscillations-in-mechanics-and-electromagnetic-induction/ as a piece of evidence that when a magnet passes the coil, which is connected to resistor some force opposes the movement of the magnet, therefore damped oscillations occur.

Few questions.

1. Is 100 turns of copper wire enough for this kind of experiment? I have fairly strong magnets.
2. As I understand the damped oscillations occur when the coil is connected to a resistor, however, the article mentions "Then we short-circuited the coil. The induced current created a magnetic field that, according to the Lenz Law, has the same effect on the magnet as a paper plate on a simple mass. Magnetic force worked exactly the same as a force of air resistance." So the question is: is the coil short-circuited or connected to the resistor?

Comment: ther are 2 parts to this, 

The first is back-emf its why motors can only spin so fast with a given supply voltage, the magnet generates a current in the coil, the current flowing through the coil generates its own magnetic field with the opposite polarity, the magnet moving through the coil is partially repelled by this, 

The resistance is like a load on a generator, its assisting this by forcing the voltage across the coil to be higher, allowing for more energy to be dissipated.

Comment: Does that mean that increasing the resistance in the coil's circuit will increase the opposing force on the magnet?

Comment: more that there is a sweet spot where it provides the most opposition, the coil can only generate a limited voltage, and a limited current, the sweet spot tends to be somewhere in the middle, this can at the least give you an idea on the range of resistance you want to try, by measuring the open circuit voltage, and the short circuit current.